# Docker ENV for Python variables

Tags: python, docker, flask

Being new to python & docker, I created a small flask app (test.py) which has two hardcoded values:

```
username = "test"
password = "12345"
```

I'm able to create a Docker image and run a container from the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6

RUN mkdir /code  
WORKDIR /code  
ADD . /code/  
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt  

EXPOSE 5000  
CMD ["python", "/code/test.py"]`
```

How can I create a ENV variable for username & password and pass dynamic values while running containers?

Answer (score 90):

Within your python code you can read env variables like:

```
import os
username = os.environ['MY_USER']
password = os.environ['MY_PASS']
print("Running with user: %s" % username)
```

Then when you run your container you can set these variables:

```
docker run -e MY_USER=test -e MY_PASS=12345 ... <image-name> ...
```

This will set the env variable within the container and these will be later read by the python script (`test.py`)

More info on [os.environ](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ) and [docker env](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-environment-variables--e---env---env-file)

Comment: Here is an article which shows how to set env variables at build time as opposed to setting them when running the container: http://blog.ruanbekker.com/blog/2018/04/07/set-docker-environment-variables-during-build-time/

Comment: Thank you, @urban! Just a point of attention for anyone not getting it to work: 
- Be aware that "-e your_env_var_name = env_var_value" must come BEFORE the image name in the RUN command

Answer (score 35):

In your Python code you can do something like this:

```
 # USERNAME = os.getenv('NAME_OF_ENV_VARIABLE','default_value_if_no_env_var_is_set')
 USERNAME = os.getenv('USERNAME', 'test')
```

Then you can create a docker-compose.yml file to run your dockerfile with:

```
version: '2'
services:
  python-container:
    image: python-image:latest
    environment:
      - USERNAME=test
      - PASSWORD=12345
```

You will run the compose file with:

```
$ docker-compose up
```

All you need to remember is to build your dockerfile that you mentioned in your question with:

```
$ docker build -t python-image .
```

Let me know if that helps. I hope that answers your question.

Comment: Sensitive data written as plain text is OK in Dockerfile / Docker-compose.yml ?

Comment: It really depends on the context.

Answer (score 3):

```html
FROM python:3

MAINTAINER <abc@test.com>

ENV username=test
    password=12345

RUN mkdir /dir/name

RUN cd /dir/name && pip3 install -r requirements.txt

WORKDIR /dir/name

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/python", "./test.py"]
```

Comment: every time you modify a docker, make sure to run the build command before running the image..

Answer (score 3):

I split my docker-compose into `docker-compose.yml` (base), `docker-compose.dev.yml`, etc., then I had this issue.

I solved it by specifying the `.env` file explicitly in the base:

```
web:
    env_file:
      - .env
```

Not sure why, according to the docs it should just work if there's an `.env` file.