# Docker compose obtain env variables from .env file and pass to docker build

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, environment-variables, containers

I'd like to be able to configure env variables for my docker containers and use them in build process with .env file

I currently have the following `.env` file:

```
SSH_PRIVATE_KEY=TEST
APP_PORT=8040
```

my **docker-compose**:

```
version: '3'
services:
  companies:
    image: companies8
    environment:
      - SSH_PRIVATE_KEY=${SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}
    ports:
      - ${APP_PORT}:${APP_PORT}
    env_file: .env
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - SSH_PRIVATE_KEY=${SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}
```

my **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM python:3.7

# set a directory for the app

COPY . .

#Accept input argument from docker-compose.yml
ARG SSH_PRIVATE_KEY=abcdef
ENV SSH_PRIVATE_KEY $SSH_PRIVATE_KEY
RUN echo $SSH_PRIVATE_KEY

# Pass the content of the private key into the container
RUN mkdir -p /root/.ssh
RUN chmod 400 /root/.ssh
RUN echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" > /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN echo "$SSH_PUBLIC_KEY" > /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
RUN chmod 400 /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN chmod 400 /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
RUN eval $(ssh-agent -s) && ssh-add /root/.ssh/id_rsa && ssh-keyscan bitbucket.org > /root/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN ssh -T git@bitbucket.org

#Install the packages
RUN pip install -r v1/requirements.txt

# Tell the port number the container should expose
EXPOSE 8040

# run the command
CMD ["python", "v1/__main__.py"]
```

and i have the same SSH_PRIVATE_KEY environment variable set on my windows with value "test1" and the build log gives me the result 'test1' from

```
ENV SSH_PRIVATE_KEY $SSH_PRIVATE_KEY
RUN echo $SSH_PRIVATE_KEY
```

not the value that's in the .env file.

I need this because some of the libraries listed in my requirements.txt are in an internal repository and I need ssh to access them, therefore the ssh private key. There might be another proper way to use this, but its the general scenario i want to achieve - to pass env variables values from .env file to my docker build

Comment: Try to leave an empty value here `ARG SSH_PRIVATE_KEY` and here `args: - SSH_PRIVATE_KEY=${SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}` (it might be well to remove `args` at all). When docker runs with `--build-arg NAME` it tries to obtain the VALUE from the environment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use environment variables in docker compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29377853/how-to-use-environment-variables-in-docker-compose)

Comment: or May be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49771684/8353711)?

Comment: Why don't you just unset the environment variable else it will override the value from `.env`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a certain overlap between `ENV` and `ARG` as shown in the image below:

[image]

Since you are having the variable already exported in the operating system, its value will be present in the image from the `ENV` instruction.

But if you do not really need the variable in the image and only in the build step (as far as I see from the `docker-compose` file), then the `ARG` instruction is enough.